# how to replace first and last quotes with two different chars in this string "{0}"

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string  `"{0}"`. I want to replace first quotes with `<Q>` and second quote with `</Q>` in javascript.

Can anyone help me with a regex to do this.

Comment: you like to replace the first quotes into what?

Answer (score 3):

I don't have any idea about `regex` but i thought it seems like this:

```js
    var str = "{0}";
    var mapObj = {
       '{':"<Q>{",
       '}':"}</Q>"
    };
    var re = new RegExp(Object.keys(mapObj).join("|"),"gi");
    str = str.replace(re, function(matched){
      return mapObj[matched.toLowerCase()];
    });
    alert(str);
```

Please correct me, if i'm wrong.

Comment: But he wrote quotes and not curly brackets, however your solution has more sense...